# malloc crashes embedded system

Tags: c, matrix, malloc, cortex-m

I am trying to multiply matrices of arbitrary sizes on a cortex M4-core. I DO need a malloc...
But I don't understand why at the first call it works and at the second call it doesnt work any more. it just jumps to the default interrupt handler FaultISR.

hereby the dissasembly code:

[image]

It fails when executing the BL command

function calls:

```
multiplyMatrices( &transFRotMatrix[0][0],3, 3, &sunMeasurements[0][0], 3, 1, *orbitalSunVector); //Works fine

multiplyMatrices( &firstRotMatrix[0][0],3, 3, &orbitalTMFV[0][0], 3, 1, *inertialTMFV); //doesn t work fine
```

code:

```
void multiplyMatrices(float *transposedMatrix, int height1, int width1, float *iSunVector,int height2, int width2, float *orbitalSunVector)
{

    int y=0;
    int x = 0;
    int row=0;
    int column =0;
    int k=0;
    int k2=0;
    float result = 0;
    float *output2=NULL;

    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    i=0;
    k=0;
    k2 = 0;


    if(width1 != height2)
    {
        //printf("unmatching matrices, error.\n\n");
        return;
    }

    output2 = malloc(height1 * width2 * sizeof(float)); //<---- jumps o FaultISR


    while(k<width1) //aantal rijen 1ste matrix
    {
        for(j=0;j<height2;j++) //aantal rijen 2de matrix
        {
            result += (*((transposedMatrix+k*width1)+j)) * (*((iSunVector+j*width2)+k2));  //1ste var:aantal kolommen 2de matrix  --2de variabele na de plus = aantal kolommen 2de matrix
            //printf("%f * %f\t + ", (*((transposedMatrix+k*width1)+j)), (*((iSunVector+j*width2)+k2)));
        }

         output2[row* width1 + column] = result;

        k2++;
        x++;
        column++;

        if(x==width2) //aantal kolommen 2de Matrix
        {
            k2=0;
            x=0;
            column=0;
            row++;
            y++;
            k++;
        }
        result = 0;

    }

    //tussenresultaat
    for(i=0;i<height1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<width2;j++)
        {
             orbitalSunVector[j * height1 + i] = output2[i* width1 + j]; //output2[i][j];

        }
    }

    free(output2);
}
```

Comment: And what is the values of `height1` and `width2`? Maybe you run out of memory? Maybe you write beyond the end that (or some other) allocated memory?

Comment: should not fail unless stack and heap are not set up properly, even if height1 and width2 are too large it should return with NULL (same case if their product is negative)

Comment: you can see the values of these variables at the function calls

Comment: So you're allocating `3 * 3 * sizeof(float)`? *Why* can't you just do e.g. `float output[9]`?

Comment: because this is not dynamic and would not work for any size of a matrix

Comment: have you tried some test cases to check malloc working ?

Comment: The how about stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger, to make sure it works as you expect? Even if you can't debug on target, the function is not target-specific so you can easily make a test program on your host system. Even if the problem doesn't happen, at least you could verify that the function works as expected.

Comment: I stepped trough the code everything works perfecty fine. It just fails there (see explanation main post). But it does work on my host system. ( I gave more than enough heap space)

Comment: have you provided your heap memory the proper permissions ? like read and write access

Comment: Do you have any flag in the FaultISR, that would tell you why it went there? It's very probably not enough memory, but that'd be good to know. Also, what is your compiler?

Comment: Not saying that this is an error, but is `*inertialTMFV` really a `float *`? You didn't mean to call the function with `&inertialTMFV`, per chance?

Comment: @Gauthier,
Hello, my issue still didn't get solved. I am working with code composer studio from texas instrument. I gave as much memory to my heap as my stack "512" I dont know in what unit this is expressed. No I wanted to give "* inertialTMFV" as a parameter.

Comment: If I recall correctly, CCstudio has a stack analysis tool. Some kind of graphical interface. Does it have one for heap?

Comment: @Gauthier Here you can see what I am using and how I set it up, unfortunately I didn't really see anything else
http://imgur.com/5Wr0iPb

Comment: @Gauthier , I edited my question and added dissasembly code, if this can help

Comment: The assembly doesn't help, I'm afraid. It doesn't show more than saving the arguments to the stack and calling of `malloc`. I guess that the `malloc` function and that it is provided without source by TI, so you cannot step through C code?

Answer (score 0):

You are overflowing your `output2` matrix in both loops due to an incorrect index calculation. You have:

```
output2[row*width1 + column] = result;
...
orbitalSunVector[j*height1 + i] = output2[i*width1 + j];
```

but you should be using `width2` in both cases since the final matrix is `width2 * height1` in size (as it is allocated):

```
output2[row*width2 + column] = result;
...
orbitalSunVector[j*height1 + i] = output2[i*width2 + j];
```

I didn't check any of your other indexes but I would test the function with a few known cases to make sure it outputs the correct results. If you had done more debugging and checked the array indexes it should have been easy to spot.

Note that the reason it worked for you the first time but not the second time is due to undefined behaviour (UB). As soon as you write past the end of `output2` you invoke UB and anything can happen. For you it happened to show up as a fault on the second call. For me it happened to fault on the first call. If you're really unlucky it may not ever fault and just silently corrupt data.

Comment: I changed it but unfortunately, this didn't solve my issue i was wrong

Comment: If you agree with the changes suggested here, please update the code in your question accordingly.

Comment: @rudolf Then you're most likely also overflowing another buffer somewhere else. (e.g. check that orbitalSunVector is as large as the code assumes it to be). But do note that even if the crash occurs in the function here, likely due to corruption of the heap , the error might be caused somewhere else.

Comment: @rudolf I would also say that @uesp's feeling that something fishy is going on with your indexes, I feel too. You have quite the number of variables, with names that are not very descriptive. `k`, `k2`, `x`, `row`, `column`, it's not very clear what these are, and what matrices or dimensions they apply to. I was going to refactor your function, but it's really something you should do yourself, starting for example by taking out the 1xN times Nx1 vector multiplication to a separate function, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `printf` in other places of your code?

[This page](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Stack_and_Heap_size_requirements) recommends starting at 0x400 for heap size, which is 1024 decimal:

> It is recommended to start with a reasonable heap size like 0x400 when
>   there is limited dynamic allocation (like printf() calls in the code),
>   and increase it as needed depending on the application.

You have 512 today, you could at least try to double that if possible, as per TI's recommendation, and see where this leads you.

[This](http://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/code_composer_studio/f/81/p/51831/183342#183342) is a related question. If you do not have a tool to watch heap allocation on the fly, try to manually fill the heap at startup (`memcpy` it with known values, such as ASCII '#==#', 0xDEADBEEF, or whatever recognizable value), then run to just before you usually crash, and watch the content of the heap in the Memory window. My best guess is that you'll find the heap is full.

Please also look if you can see error flag registers while you are in the FaultISR. Often there is something somewhere telling you *why* you came here.

I am not sure about TI's implementation of `malloc`, but they may save an error value. I'd not bet on that one, since it would probably return NULL in that case, rather than crash.